# Como obtener una clave a traves de un valor, diccionario en python

Tags: python

tengo un diccionario
dic={"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
Tengo entendido que existe un comando para obtener el valor a través de una clave dic.get("a","x")
pero quiero hacerlo al revés. Tener una clave a traves de su valor. ¿Como lo hago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si usas Python 3.x tienes esta forma de hacerlo:

```
dic = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "j": 23}

print(list(dic.keys())[list(dic.values()).index(23)])
```

Lo que hace es generar una lista a partir del diccionario , luego busca el valor indicado en el index y obtiene la key en esa posicion

Answer (score 1):

La clase `dict` no dispone de ningún método para conseguir la clave o claves (**varias claves pueden tener el mismo valor**, pero no a la inversa) asociadas a un determinado valor, digamos un `dict.get` "inverso". No obstante solo tienes que iterar sobre las parejas con la vista `dict.items` y usar un condicional para filtrar las claves asociadas al valor que quieres:

```
def get_keys_with_value(dic, value):
    return [key for key, val in dic.items() if val == value]
```

> ```
> >>> dic = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 1}
> >>> keys = get_keys_with_value(dic, 1)
> >>> keys
> ['a', 'd']
>
> >>> dic = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
> >>> keys = get_keys_with_value(dic, 1)
> >>> keys
> ['a']
>
> >>> dic = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
> >>> keys = get_keys_with_value(dic, 4)
> >>> keys
> []
> ```